# Form and Textcontent in Block

Tags: 7, forms, blocks

I'm having problems with adding a form and text-content into a block. To get both, form and text, into my block, I use `render()` on my form, but I read, this isn't the best way to do, but don't found another way. Anyone knows how to get both into the content without using `render()`?

```
function commerce_bulk_invoice_block_view($block_name = '') {
    $block = array();
    if ($block_name == 'showinvoiceoptions') {
        $block['content'] = '<div id="invoice-block">';
        if(!isset($_SESSION['selected_entities'])) {
            $block['content'] .= 'select a product first';
        } else {
            $block['content'] .= '<h1>SESSION Variables:</h1>';
            foreach($entity_array as $book) {               
                $block['content'] .= '<pre>';
                $block['content'] .= print_r( $book, true );
                $block['content'] .= '</pre>';
            }
        }
        $block['content'] .= '</div>';

        $form = drupal_get_form('commerce_bulk_invoice_form');
        $block['content'] .= render($form);
    }
    return $block;
}
```

Comment: If you let me some time, I'll try to explain to you how I did that once.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
function commerce_bulk_invoice_block_view($block_name = '') {
  $block = array();
  if ($block_name == 'showinvoiceoptions') {
    $content = '<div id="invoice-block">';
    if(!isset($_SESSION['selected_entities'])) {
        $content .= 'select a product first';
    } else {
        $content .= '<h1>SESSION Variables:</h1>';
        foreach($entity_array as $book) {               
            $content .= '<pre>';
            $content .= print_r( $book, true );
            $content .= '</pre>';
        }
    }

    $content .= '</div>';  

    $build['content']=array('#markup' => $content);
    $build['form']=drupal_get_form('commerce_bulk_invoice_form');

    $block['content'] = $build;
 }
 return $block;
}
```